# Passing variables between PS stages on different agents in jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline with two (powershell) stages, each running on a different node/slave.

I'm trying to set a variable during the first stage (on node 1) and use it afterwards on the next stage (on node 2) - however, I couldn't find a way to pass this variable between them.

It's worth clarifying that this variable is being set dynamically in stage 1, meaning that solutions like declaring an `env:var` using `script` or `def` or `environment` didn't help (I tried many combinations) - the value can vary every time I run the pipeline.

I tried setting a new value for `env var` in stage 1, but it looks like it only affects its value in the context of the running stage.

(yes, it must be in powershell and on different nodes)

this is the basic idea of the pipeline (which doesn't work)

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'Node1' }

stages{ 
    stage('Calculate'){
        steps {
            git changelog: false, credentialsId: 'user', poll: false, url: 'https://mygit.com/myrepo.git'

            powershell '''
            $currentVersion=[version]$(git describe --tags)
            $newVersion=New-Object -TypeName System.Version($currentVersion.Major, $currentVersion.Minor, $currentVersion.Build, ($currentVersion.Revision + 1))
            '''
        }
    }

    stage('Act'){
        agent { label 'Node2' }
        steps {
            powershell "Write-Host $env:newVersion"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my scripts I define a var above the pipeline tag and then I use

```
returnValue = powershell returnStdout: true, script: '...'
```

to generate my Powershell output.

```
'returnStdout: true'
```

is the key to receive your output from your PowerShell script.

In another stage I use bat to call a PowerShell script and sned my var to it:

```
bat "powershell -File script.ps1 ${returnValue}"
```

Hope that helps.

Greetings

Comment: This won't help ! You helped to get an output from command, but once you got that output and you want to use it as variable on an other slave it won't be reachable !

Comment: Did you get any solutin for this?